# Load an csv file for SVM predict in OpenCV using C++

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, svm

I have a .csv file that I want to load in order to use the predict SVM function using OpenCV 3.4.0 and C++, but I can't get it right. How can this operation be done in OpenCV 3.4.0?
This is the way I'm trying to use the predict function and load the csv file:

```
Mat srct = imread("D:/.../00024_00020.ppm", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

if (!srct.data)
    cout << "Could not read the test image!" << endl;

Mat sout;
srct.copyTo(sout);
resize(sout, sout, cvSize(32, 32));

vector<float> derst;
cv::HOGDescriptor hog(cv::Size(32, 32), cv::Size(16, 16), cv::Size(4, 4), cv::Size(4, 4), 9);
hog.compute(sout, derst, cv::Size(8, 8), cv::Size(0, 0));

Ptr<ml::SVM> svm = ml::SVM::create();
svm->load("D:/.../GT-00014.csv"); //HERE AN ERROR IS THROWN RELATED WITH A MEMORY LOCATION
int response = (int)svm->predict(derst);
```

The file I want to load is from GTSRB at this location: http://benchmark.ini.rub.de/?section=gtsrb&subsection=dataset#Downloads.

Any thoughts on this issue?

**EDIT 1:** 
The error thrown:
[image]

Comment: `HERE AN ERROR IS THROWN` Be more specific; what error exactly?

Comment: try svm = svm->load... load is a static function and returns loaded SVM.

Comment: @ildjarn I've attached the thrown error

Comment: @DmitriiZ. The same error is thrown, I think the **load()** function cannot load an .csv file.

Comment: @sixfeet : The error is telling you that a `cv::Exception` was thrown and never caught. Try catching it and seeing what the error message is (i.e. call the `what()` member function).